# Human name based on the root “Fury”

Tags: names

If you want to create one pair of names (masculine & feminine) based on the root word “Fury”, what are the correct names based on principles that are used in English language?
As a non-English person, I thought of these two: Furex (M) & Furexina (F) but they seem kind of weird to me.

Comment: You can use *Fury* itself as a name for either a male or female. Authors, and parents, name their kids all kinds of weird things. Furex and Furexina: nah, these are way to foreign sounding. They sound like Asterix and no one in the USA knows who the hell he is.

Comment: Well, you can certainly name a horse [Fury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fury_(TV_series)).

Comment: @AlanCarmack *Furex* sounds like it should be a prophylactic aimed at [furries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furry_fandom).

Comment: Inquiring minds want to know: Names for what?  A line of serving dishes? Company names? Kittens? A ship and its boat?  A man's first name and a woman’s first name? The farmer and his wife? Space aliens? Comets? Superheroes? Hamlets? A disease and its cure? Spirits of justice and vengeance? Slang for street drugs? Signs to hang on paired lavatory doors in a public place? Pagan holidays? Titania’s fairies? Special seasons in the calendar? New kinds of superflu?

Comment: On the model of [Cruella de Vil](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=cruella+de+vil), Furella and Furellus

Comment: @tchrist If you take a look at the question again, when I say Masculine & Feminine, it means that I'm looking for names for living things such that they could be divided into natural genders: Male & Female (Humans, Horses, Flies, Ants, Cows, )... It's not that hard to interpret it out of the content.

Comment: @ab2 Is it natural for a native English?

Comment: @Merlot Latterian It sounds odd to my native English ear.  Any name based on Fury would sound odd.  They would be OK for the names of cats (note play on the word fur) but not for the names of babies or of large dogs,  If you are writing Sci Fi or Fantasy, OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Furia, for the female character, from the Latin root of the word "fury".

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=fury

Comment: "Furia" seems good and naturally English.

Answer (score 3):

There are no rules for this, and nobody can tell you what is "correct".

I suspect that if somebody wanted to make a name based on "fury" they would just use "Fury". The singer [Billy Fury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billy_Fury) adopted it as a stage name (albeit as his surname, not his first name).

But if you wanted to use Furex and Furexina, nobody would stop you: they would sound foreign though.

Comment: Well that's the point. I do not want them to sound strange.

Comment: I don't also want to use the root itself because it Is kind of furious to call someone Fury

Comment: Billy Fury's name was an adoption, not an invention, there's an [Irish surname](https://www.houseofnames.com/fury-family-crest) derived from names like O'Fearain. and an [English surname](http://www.surnamedb.com/Surname/Fury) possibly derived from the Norman French for flower. As it's a surname you can use it as a forename, there's plenty of precedent for that.